# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am getting this

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
```

error when i used devise gem

error in console is

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"kwJU2b47XvXj9hNV1HAdttW/rvetDepAVCn+jPvndy8=", "user"=>{"email"=>"nagarajureddy@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
```

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

```
 ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):  activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:21:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
```

Please  any one help me

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your application controller and restart the server, It's because of Strong Parameters in Rails4.

```
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, password_confirmation)  }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, password_confirmation) }
  end
```